# Displaying Each Element of an Array One by One

Tags: iphone, objective-c, recursion

I have an array of SKSpriteNodes (although, for the purposes of this question, they may as well be UIViews [concept should be the same either way]). I am attempting to add the first element to the view, begin a 3 second delay, add the second element to the view, begin a 3 second delay, etc.. My initial thought would be a recursive function using NSTimer, but I'm not sure that would be the best way to go. Any tips?

Comment: `for(int i=0; i < [yourArray count]; ++i)`

Comment: @nhgrif The question was how to display each element one by one with a 3 second delay in between each element.

Comment: And what's wrong with `NSTimer`?

Comment: It seems clunky to have an NSTimer calling the method it's created in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use `SKAction` with `performSelector`:

```
self.nextIndex = 0;
SKAction *action = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:3.0],
                                        [SKAction performSelector:@(addNextItem) onTarget:self]]];
[self runAction:action];
```

Then, define `addNextItem`:

```
- (void)addNextItem
{
    [self addChild:myArray[self.nextIndex++]];
    if(self.nextIndex < [myArray count]) {
        SKAction *action = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:self.nextWait],
                                                [SKAction performSelector:@(addNextItem) onTarget:self]]];
        [self runAction:action];
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

If you're familiar with blocks, you can use blocks for this type of thing as well:

```
__block NSUInteger index = 0;
void (^addItem)(void) = ^(void) {
    SKNode *node = myArray[index++];
    [self addChild:node];
};
SKAction *action = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:3.0],
                                        [SKAction runBlock:addItem],
                                        [SKAction waitForDuration:3.0],
                                        [SKAction runBlock:addItem],
                                        [SKAction waitForDuration:3.0],
                                        [SKAction runBlock:addItem],
                                        [SKAction waitForDuration:3.0],
                                        [SKAction runBlock:addItem]]];
[self runAction:action];
```

Here are some references for using blocks:

- [Apple: Getting Started with Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html)
- [How To Use Blocks in iOS 5 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9328/creating-a-diner-app-using-blocks-part-1)

Comment: Hmm, this seems like a nice solution. I'm relatively unfamiliar to the concept of blocks however, do you have any good links? Also, what if the delay time has to be able to change b/w elements being added? Would this solution scale to that scenario?

Comment: @Monkeyanator Hmm... Blocks are pretty tricky. They're a form of closure, so if you're not familiar with closures, then there might be a steep learning curve. I added a second option that avoids blocks that might work better for you.